# K is a subgroup of G. Determine whether the given cosets are disjoint or identical

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Let $G= U_{32}$ and $ K = \langle9 \rangle$. Determine whether the following cosets are identical or disjoint:

(a) $K17$ and $K19$

(b) $K9$ and $K25$

For part (a),  So far I know $G$ is the set of units in $\mathbb Z/32\mathbb Z$ which is $\{1,3,5,7,\dots,31\}$
and I have K is the set $\{9,17,25,1\}$ 
A little lost on what I am looking for next

Is it enough to say that since $K17$ and $K19$ are both not in the set $K$, that they are disjoint? And in part (b), since $K9$ and $K25$ are both in $K$, they are identical?

Comment: Please format your questions in Mathjax in the future, and keep the body of the question self-contained (so the question is not just in the title.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $17\in K$, $K17=K$. And, since $19\notin K$, $K19\neq K$. And since $K17\neq K19$, they are disjoint (two cosets are either identical or disjoint).

On the other hand, $K9=K25=K$.

Comment: Ah! yes it just hit me! thank you for your help. I wasn't sure if I had to show anything else